# Electrical Code issues with light switches and Arduinos

Tags: arduino, ac, relay, wifi

Are there any electrical code issues with placing an electronic circuit inside the light switch box of a house?

I am planning on adding a WIFI (8266) and relay control to a light switch.

Does anyone know if there are any code issues with placing electronic circuits in the same box as the light switch?

I live in Texas if that makes any difference.
Thanks

Paul.

Comment: Yes, obviously, lots of people know if there are code issues with what you propose. Anyone that's actually read the code, for one. How many people out there know something is off topic, as it's not about electrical engineering. Also, if you know so little about the electrical code, you shouldn't be messing with line power wiring.

Comment: You already have some valid comments. The bottom line, though, is that if the home is yours and you aren't renting it to anyone and you are willing to risk having no insurance coverage if an electrical fire is traced to your device and if you remove it before you sell your home, then you are pretty much allowed to do what you want. A licensed electrician will not be able to work around or near it, though, and they may refuse to work if they even know about it until you remove it. I assume you know what you are doing, of course.  If you don't, then you just shouldn't do it, at all.

Comment: @Olin, yes I have read the code, but it wasn't obvious. The question did comply with the help center rules as it concerned an electronic design and did not involve a consumer product or PC programming. I think you were a bit harsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USA National Electrical Code (NEC) requires that anything installed in a device or wiring box of a power distribution system must be listed by a nationally recognized testing laboratory such as Underwriters Laboratories or Intertek's ETL SEMKO. States and lower jurisdictions base their codes on NEC.